# How to trigger authentication in typo3 v12

Tags: typo3

I send a form field 'logintype' with value 'login' to a custom controller (or for testing just to the root page), but my custom AuthenticationService is not called.

When I use the standard felogin-plugin then it is called.
In typo3 v11 I had another approach, there I just send the form field and check later if a cookie was set (and that worked).
I think just sending a form field 'logintype' with value 'login' only does not trigger authentification anymore?
What has to be done?